# Matching n number of lines in text to a regex any order using python

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, python-2.7, scripting

I have to match the configuration of a filewall from a input file. In input file I'll specify a regex. This regex should match the output of the command from firewall.

Suppose the firewall output is as below

```
ssh 192.217.254.20 255.255.255.255 junk_string
ssh 192.217.248.0 255.255.252.0 junk_string
ssh 192.217.254.21 255.255.255.255 junk_string
ssh 192.217.254.25 255.255.255.255 junk_string
ssh 192.217.254.38 255.255.255.255 junk_string
ssh 192.217.254.42 255.255.255.255 junk_string
ssh 192.115.24.64 255.255.255.224 junk_string
ssh 192.217.240.0 255.255.252.0 junk_string
ssh 192.217.236.0 255.255.252.0 junk_string
ssh 192.217.255.78 255.255.255.255 junk_string
```

I want to match 9 lines as below regex.

```
(sh 192.217.((254.(20|21|25|38|42)|255.78) 255.255.255.255|(240|248|236).0 255.255.252.0) [^ ]*\r\n?){9}
```

But the rule will not match because of the 7th line when I use this regex with re.match or re.search.

Is there any way to check this regex in any order. I mean it should match 9 lines, even if some unwanted lines are there in between.

Update,
This is how i use it

```
 if re.match(result_expected[command],actual_result,re.M|re.I):
      if verbose == "True":
        print("Command output and expected output Matched")

 result_expected - is our regex I have given above.
 actual_result - is the 10 lines which is output of the command executed on the firewall.
```

ok. To make it more clear, my pattern works for the following 14 lines.

```
pattern='(ssh 192.(168.((254.(2|6|20|21|25|38|42)|255.78|255.91|255.92) 255.255.255.255|(240|248|236).0 255.255.252.0)|115.24.64 255.255.255.224) [^ ]*\r?\n?){14}'

ssh 192.168.240.0 255.255.252.0 junk_string
ssh 192.168.248.0 255.255.252.0 junk_string
ssh 192.168.236.0 255.255.252.0 junk_string
ssh 192.168.254.42 255.255.255.255 junk_string
ssh 192.168.254.25 255.255.255.255 junk_string
ssh 192.168.254.21 255.255.255.255 junk_string
ssh 192.168.255.78 255.255.255.255 junk_string
ssh 192.168.254.20 255.255.255.255 junk_string
ssh 192.168.254.38 255.255.255.255 junk_string
ssh 192.115.24.64 255.255.255.224 junk_string
ssh 192.168.254.2 255.255.255.255 junk_string
ssh 192.168.254.6 255.255.255.255 junk_string
ssh 192.168.255.91 255.255.255.255 junk_string
ssh 192.168.255.92 255.255.255.255 junk_string
```

But when we add another line

```
ssh 172.31.1.30 255.255.255.255 junk_string
```

then the regex fails for

```
ssh 192.168.240.0 255.255.252.0 junk_string
ssh 192.168.248.0 255.255.252.0 junk_string
ssh 192.168.236.0 255.255.252.0 junk_string
ssh 192.168.254.42 255.255.255.255 junk_string
ssh 192.168.254.25 255.255.255.255 junk_string
ssh 192.168.254.21 255.255.255.255 junk_string
ssh 192.168.255.78 255.255.255.255 junk_string
ssh 192.168.254.20 255.255.255.255 junk_string
ssh 192.168.254.38 255.255.255.255 junk_string
ssh 172.31.1.30 255.255.255.255 junk_string
ssh 192.115.24.64 255.255.255.224 junk_string
ssh 192.168.254.2 255.255.255.255 junk_string
ssh 192.168.254.6 255.255.255.255 junk_string
ssh 192.168.255.91 255.255.255.255 junk_string
ssh 192.168.255.92 255.255.255.255 junk_string
```

my requirement is the regex should work as long as the 14 lines are there. Even if the extra line comes before/after/in between.

How can we achieve this?

Comment: you are not showing how its incorporated in your code, but is not clear why you even need to use regex. python has powerful string methods so if your firewall output is available as string, just look if x in string(line by line if read from file)

Comment: otherwise show your code how you use re; u can do python loop and check re for each line for may be slow but working solution for example

Comment: A quick glance shows that input string contains `ssh` while you are trying to match `sh`.

Comment: I don't understand why you decided to use the final part of the regex ` [^ ]*\r\n?` First of all, I believe `\n` matches all types of newline, so you probably don't need `\r`. If that wasn't the case the regex is still wrong because it means that you *always* expect `\r` at end of line and only the `\n` may be missing. Anyway I'd have just written it as `.*\n?` or even `.*\s?`. The dot does not match newlines by default.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match a dot literally you should escape it `\.` or else it would mean to match any character. There is also a leading `s` missing, now it says `sh`.

If you use an alternation and don't want to capture the values you could use a non capturing group `(?:`

To to match all the lines except `ssh 192.115.24.64 255.255.255.224 junk_string` you might use [findall](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#finding-all-adverbs).

Without capturing groups you could match your lines with:

[`ssh 192\.217\.(?:254\.(?:2[015]|38|42)|255\.78|24[08]\.0|236\.0) 255\.255\.(?:255\.255|252\.0) [^ ]*\r?\n|\r`](https://regex101.com/r/j9OJKJ/1)

[Demo Python](http://rextester.com/VRTQ61645)